# Using spring forms in templates

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I have a registration form in my header.jsp which includes fields; name-email-password.

When user clicks "register" button, it will be POSTed to my registration controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUserAccount(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") RegistrationForm userAccountData,
                                      BindingResult result, ... )
```

Since I'm using spring form tag, I include an empty user object for data binding in my index view.

The problem is I keep getting

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

This form resides in my header file, so it is accessible from all pages. Do I have to add a user object to every `ModelAndView` or is there a neater way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to do the following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ModelAdvice {

   @ModelAttribute
   public RegistrationForm registrationForm() {
     return new RegistrationForm();
   }

}
```

`@ControllerAdvice` is used when you want something to apply to all controllers. In this case you want to apply the `@ModelAttribute` to all the controllers since as you say the registration form is in all the pages.

For more find grained control, you would probably want to implement a [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that would add to the the required data to `HttpServletRequest` when needed